# Change the production JS code after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Hello everyone.**

How are you?

I have got an offer from a client that I have to change the built version of the ReactJS code. You know that it is kind long messy code that we can't just change  ( I think that ).

Is there a way to somehow parse it and make it like React?

Thank your answares in advance.

Have a good day.

I tried to analyized and make a change. I tried to fetch a data from an API and set some variable with the response. I expected some changes but I know React so it won't change 'cause lack of the re-render. (  States, forceUpdate etc..)

Comment: There are several ways to do this, sourcemaps is one of them. However, why exactly would you want to modify compiled code instead of the source ? Seems like a very bad idea to start with

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You want to take React code, change it somehow, and make it more like React?

Comment: @BJRINT The client has only the production built code :D And I am a bad coder to not be able to do.

Comment: @Andy I want the production-built code to look like regular React code.

Comment: That would defeat the whole purpose of a production build. Why does your client want this? Can't you just link them to Github etc and just show them them the source code? I'm assuming you control it?

Comment: @Andy My client is something like how just owns the site and doesn't care about the whole production. (upgrade if he wants). He just sent me ftp cred. Logged in and there were just production-built files. He doesn't know much more about that.

Comment: I sympathise. But the fact that they don't understand how modern JS development works doesn't make less true. "Accept a change, write some code, test it, rebuild, and then redeploy". Otherwise your production code and your development code will be out of sync. You either need to gently tell them "this is how it works", or have your manager bring them up to speed. @Molesz

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.